# Improve file copy process using wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, smb

I am trying to write an application in C# where it can copy data in two ways.

1. Use .Net CopyFile method of System.IO namespace to copy files from source to destination machine. In this way, it copies using SMB protocols.
2. Use stream reader to read in chunks from client files and send it to an connected WCF service hosted on destination machine. WCF service will write the data on destination machine disk. I am doing reading and sending 1 MB of data at a time.

In my scenarios, second way with WCF service is working slower as compared to SMB (first approach) on 1 Gbps network.

Some one suggested to use TCP window scaling. Please suggest if that will be useful here or let me know the way to improve it.

WCF implementation with netTcpbinding is working faster than SMB in most of the case. but it stucked when client has multiple nics installed on destination machine hosting WCF service. But in this scenario normal copy (first approach) is working  faster.

Comment: I can imagine you need a very very good wcf implementation to be faster than the windows api or smb copy methods...with all the serializing and deserializing overhead I don't think wcf is a good way to implement that.

Comment: @jdweng What is the point of Gigabit ethernet if it is capped to 100Mbps?

Comment: WCF with its default data shape configuration is a poor choice for sending large files/streams.  The reason is that WCF, being a SOAP implementation will send data as SOAP messages (nice verbose XML data structures) over the transport.  You can improve this somewhat by using the `BinaryFormatter` which eliminates the XML.  You might also want to look into WCF Streams